# Parallel inner join

Tags: c#, linq, plinq, parallel-extensions

I want to perform inner join between products and categories with using PLINQ. But I'm not sure if I should call AsParallel method for both collections.

```
// PLINQ  - Option 1
jointTables =     from c in Homework02.categories.AsParallel()
                  join p in Homework02.productList on c.Name equals p.Category
                  select new { Category = c, Product = p };

// PLINQ  - Option 2
jointTables = from c in Homework02.categories.AsParallel()
              join p in Homework02.productList.AsParallel() on c.Name equals p.Category
              select new { Category = c, Product = p };
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use Option 2, i.e. explicitly calling `AsParallel()` on the second sequence as well.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/dd384155%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `Join` overload where the second sequence is of type `IEnumerable<TInner>` :

> This Join overload should never be called. **This method is marked as
>   obsolete and always throws NotSupportedException when invoked.**

Also note the obsolete-attribute on the declaration:

```
[ObsoleteAttribute(@"The second data source of a binary operator 
                    must be of type System.Linq.ParallelQuery<T> 
                    rather than System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>. 
                    To fix this problem, use the AsParallel() extension
                    method to convert the right data source to
                    System.Linq.ParallelQuery<T>.")]
public static ParallelQuery<TResult> Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this ParallelQuery<TOuter> outer,
    IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
    Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector,
    Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
    Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector
)
```